# How to automatically include all js files inside the html of an express application?

Tags: node.js, express

I feel completely stupid trying to use node...

I'm using Node.JS with express. I want to automatically include all my client JS scripts into my HTML page. This is extremely straight-forward in the other languages I know (PHP or C#), but I can't get it to work...

I've tried doing it using glob directly in the ejs file:

views/partials/footer.ejs:

```
<% glob(path.join(dir, "../public/js/**/*.js"), function(er, files){
    files.forEach(function(file){
    %>
<script src="<%=file %>" ></script>
<%
});
});
 %>
```

routes/index.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var glob = require('glob');
var path = require('path');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

  res.render('index', {
        title: 'Express',
        glob: glob,
        path: path,
        dir: __dirname
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

The code runs, and the partial file is included (if I place text inside, I see it). But when this code runs, it add no files, even though there are definitely files in that directory (public/app/module.js for example).

It seems to me that this is something very basic, but I haven't found anyone asking about it, and no easy way to do it. It seems very critical, especially for frameworks which require many files, such as angular.

What is the right way to do this with angular, and why didn't this work?